# JFrame loses transparency trait once components added

Tags: java, jframe, transparent, paintcomponent

I want to make an overlay window that has a transparent frame with non transparent children. I was successful when making the transparent window and even was successful when adding a test child to see if it work. But as soon as I replace that test code with my paintComponent... I get a white background. Anyone know why?

```
package blahh;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;;

public class LoadingFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoadingFrame Class = new LoadingFrame();
        Class.frameChar();


    }

    public void frameChar(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        B b = new B();


        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout()); 
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("test code");
        frame.add(b);
        frame.pack();
    }

 public class B extends JPanel{
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);


        }

 }   
}
```

Comment: Your panel is opaque by default, consider call `setOpaque(false)` on it when you construct it

Comment: Ah you got it man! You're a genius. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPanel` is opaque by default, combined with `BorderLayout`, this will make it cover the entire frame, making it appear opaque.  You need to call `setOpaque(false)` on it to make it see through

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    B b = new B();
    b.setOpaque(false);


    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
    // I'd prefer to override getPreferredSize of B
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
    frame.add(b);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

ps- You should also call `setVisible` last where possible, it just reduces the possibility of your components not showing up randomly